# wxTextCtrl change value

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

my partner and I have been searching for ways to load a value into a wxTextCtrl box and have had no success. Are you aware of any tricks that can help assign a value to it for example after clicking a button? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
wxTextCtrl * myCtrl = new wxTextCtrl(this,-1)
wxString value;
...
myCtrl->ChangeValue( value );
```

Answer (score 2):

The safest way to change the value of `wxTextCtrl` is to use its [ChangeValue()](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_text_entry.html#a8c52ab71f51c8f80556c2c8e763cbca1) method. If you need the change to result in the same `wxEVT_TEXT_CHANGED` event as would be sent if the user entered the text interactively, then you should use [SetValue()](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_text_entry.html#a90f876b2dd83ba5c97ba0c193b386e9f). Note that a lot of existing code uses `SetValue()` even though it would have been better to use `ChangeValue()` just because the latter is relatively recent (only half a decade or so...).

Finally, do *not* use `SetLabel()`, this is not supposed to work at all for wxTextCtrl contents and while it does, initially by accident and now for compatibility reasons, under Windows, it is not guaranteed to work under the other platforms.

Comment: Interesting.  Is there some way you can produce a deprecated compiler warning?  SetLabel is ubiquitous in my code.

Comment: Unfortunately no because we don't want to break existing MSW-only code using it.